# Calculate table 3 using Table 1 and Table 2 data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am tryin to solve the ID issue, I am able to solve Table 3 value for Date, VarX, and VarY but there is an issue getting ID as 1 and 2 for the required dates below.

The objective of this problem is to get Table 3 with required data along with ID. So the output in Table 3 should contain ID, Date, VarX, and VarY.

```
+---------------------------+
|         TABLE 1:          |
+---------------------------+
| ID  Date        VarX VarY |
| 1   30-03-2019  35    65  |
| 2   30-03-2019  45    12  |
| 3   30-03-2019  15    45  | 
+---------------------------+

+---------------------------+
|         TABLE 2:          |
+---------------------------+
| ID  Date        VarX VarY |
| 1   01-04-2019  25    45  |
| 1   05-04-2019        22  |
| 1   08-04-2019  29        |
| 2   03-04-2019  59    18  |
| 2   05-04-2019  48        |
| 2   09-04-2019  31        |
| 2   14-04-2019        26  |
+---------------------------+

+----------------------------+
|         TABLE 3:           |
+----------------------------+
|  ID  Date        VarX VarY |
|   1  08-04-2019   29  22   |
|   2  14-04-2019   31  26 
|   3  30-03-2019   15  45
+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if necessary filter by `df1['ID']` column use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df2 = df2[df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID'])]
```

If empty values are missing `NaN`s use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html), it return last non missing values:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('ID', as_index=False).last()
print (df3)
   ID        Date  VarX  VarY
0   1  08-04-2019  29.0  22.0
1   2  14-04-2019  31.0  26.0
```

Else:

```
df3 = df2.replace('', np.nan).groupby('ID', as_index=False).last()
```

EDIT: Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with match by `ID` converted to `index` in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df11 = df1.set_index('ID')
df22 = df2.groupby('ID').last()

df11.update(df22)

df3 = df11.reset_index()
print (df3)

   ID        Date  VarX  VarY
0   1  08-04-2019  29.0  45.0
1   2  14-04-2019  26.0  18.0
2   3  30-03-2019  15.0  45.0
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, what if TB1 has one new column for

ID  DATE          VarX  VarY
3   30-03-2019  15      22

How we'll get latest data in Table 3 from both Table 1 and 2?

Comment: @dnxtgn - Can you explain more? Ther are 4 columns like in comment above

Comment: I have updated the question. I need to pull latest ID i.e. 1,2 and 3. ID 3 is in Table 1 and Table 2 contains latest value so Table 3 will have latest ID value from both table.